# Testing 3rd party API through SSL with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm integrating with a 3rd party API and their documentation contains the following information:

Only requests through an SSL connection are allowed. The G2 SSL Certificate for api.{domainname}.com is signed by Go Daddy. As of this writing, the certificate properties are:

```
Certificate
   Version 3
   Serial Number:  04 14 56 13 ea b3 4a
   Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
   Issuer:

C = US, S = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2

   Validity:
      From:  2015-March-03 03:09:50 GMT
      To:    2016-March-03 03:09:50 GMT
```

Included with this documentation is a link to the following page:

https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

My question is as I'm working on integrating with the API and am developing code, how do I go about getting a certificate and installing it so I can test my code?   This is a standard Rails development environment using Webrick.

Comment: This certificate has already expired (in March this year)

Comment: Understood, but let's assume there is a certificate with a valid expiry.  I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from documentation (http://www.shiprightsolutions.com/developers.html) the API requires the request to be over SSL, this only mean the url will start with https:// you don`t need to install any certificate to make a request. 
Although, it uses an API key to identify the client (your app), so you must pass it along with the request in a custom header they call SRS-ApiKey. At the documentation
you pointed, they say you must send them an e-mail requesting a API key to be used for test.

Once you have the key you can test a request with cURL. Details including sample requests and responses can be downloaded here (http://www.shiprightsolutions.com/documents/SRS-API-093015.zip)

```
curl -H "SRS-ApiKey: YOUR API KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST - d@scenario1-request.json https://apiplay.shiprightsolutions.com/v1/order -v
```

In your rails app you can use a HTTP client library like Faraday (https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

```
require 'faraday'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://apiplay.shiprightsolutions.com/v1') do |faraday|
    faraday.response :logger
    faraday.headers['SRS-ApiKey'] = 'XXX'
    faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter    # make requests with Net::HTTP
end

response = conn.post do |req|
    req.url '/order'
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.body = '{ "id": 1, "param": "value" }'
end

puts response.body
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.   But would not the certificate have to correspond to a legitimate domain name?   How would I go about acquiring a certificate for my local dev box (my macbook).

Comment: Can you tell which API you are working with ? It would help to take a look at the docs.

Comment: You can find the documentation here: http://www.shiprightsolutions.com/developers.html

Comment: I think they do not require Mutual SSL, I have updated the answer, let me know if I got it right this time.

Comment: I do have a key and when I try it, I get a 403 forbidden error as their documentation indicates.   It doesn't help that the error message is a generic API KEY missing or invalid error.

Comment: Actually it says an invalid key would result in a 404. You will get a 403 if you make a non SSL request starting with http:// instead of https://

Comment: That's interesting considering the PDF documentation available at the bottom of the page says an invalid key will result in a 403.   Sigh!

Comment: = / that's a boomer. Sorry I couldn't help, I would try myself if I had a key. Did you use the SRS-ApiKey header ?

Comment: I got in touch with their support and it was indeed a problem with the API Key.  It works now.  Thanks for your help.   I'm going to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You are welcome, but I think you should delete this question since it won`t help others much